# App Crashes when I try to delete List Element-Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried making a dynamic list where the user can add elements by writing a text and pushing a button. The user also should be able to delete elements by clicking on them for a longer time.
The code can be build and I can start it. But while the adding works just fine, everytime I try to delete a specific element the App stops running.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> ModuleList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> MyAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button addButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ModuleList=new ArrayList<>();
        addButton=findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        MyAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addModule(view);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                deleteItem(view, position);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void addModule(View view) {
        EditText input =findViewById(R.id.textInput);
        String itemText=input.getText().toString();

        if(!(itemText.equals("")))
        {
            ModuleList.add(itemText);
            MyAdapter.add(itemText);
            MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            input.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert Module^...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void deleteItem(View view,int i)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ModuleList.remove(i);
        MyAdapter.remove(ModuleList.get(i));
        MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The XML codes looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    </ListView>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textInput"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF5722"
        android:text="+" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm new to Android Studio, so might be an obvious mistake, but I can't find it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are removing item at index i, and then trying to fetch it right after... of course the app will crash. 

ModuleList.remove(i); <- you removed it. 
MyAdapter.remove(ModuleList.get(i)); <- you are fetching it after you removed it.

Perhaps try to switch those two statements order?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Switching both lines solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModuleList.remove(i);
MyAdapter.remove(ModuleList.get(i));
```

It seems that, in your Adapter, you want to delete an item which doesn't exist anymore. Try to switch these 2 lines.

Comment: Oh man, that was a dumb mistake I made. That solved the problem. Thank you very much